# About how fast can a small fish swim before experiencing turbulent flow around its body?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence, order-of-magnitude

About how fast can a small fish swim before experiencing turbulent flow around its body? An Engineering Problem! Please go through this question step by step. :D

Comment: First tell us what have you tried!(you should do your homework first.)

Comment: I've got no idea to be honest! This came up in an Engineering interview. I don't even know where to start!

Comment: Think of it the other way: how fast can a flow be on a rigid surface before the flow is turbulent?

Comment: Doesn't this problem say anything about the diameter of the pipe the fish is going through?

Comment: @user689 Why must the fish be in a pipe for turbulence to occur?

Comment: @tpg2114 it's not about the pipe, it is about the diameter, see the answer for more information.

Comment: Since it is a job interview question I would take the question strictly,i.e. the answer will be the maximum speed physiognomically possible for the small fish.

Comment: this is a stupid question

Comment: it is not a simple problem http://iopscience.iop.org/1742-6596/318/2/022042/pdf/1742-6596_318_2_022042.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Let's make some assumptions. First, assume the fish is rigid. Second, let's assume he's not flapping. Third, I guess let's assume it's a male fish since I said "he."

We'll also assume this is 2D because we're looking for an approximation. I would approximate the fish as an airfoil. [NACA airfoils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil) are a pretty good choice because they are analytically defined and very well studied. We'll take the NACA 0015 airfoil shown below (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NACA0015_a.png), and only because this was the airfoil they had a picture of... really any NACA 00XX airfoil is fine so long as XX isn't too big).

[image: Image of NACA 0015 airfoil.]

The Reynolds number is what we're after here. Transition to turbulence over an airfoil occurs at roughly $R \approx 3 \times 10^6$ (any intro to viscous flow book will show you this) and the Reynolds number is defined as:

$$ R = \frac{v L}{\nu}$$

where $\rho$ is the fluid density, $v$ is the object velocity, $L$ is the length scale describing the body and $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity of the fluid. So you take $R$ to be $3 \times 10^6$ and you need to know the density and kinematic viscosity of water. Then you need to estimate the length of the fish, or you can report your answer in "velocity-fish length" units, i.e. $vL$. It's really just a simple manipulation to compute that.

Comment: I sense gender bias here ! :P atleast leave poor fishes alone, maybe call it, **it** ! Btw, very well formed answer and more accurate too !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can work,

[Reynold's number](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) is defined for a pipe as ${(\rho v d)}/{\eta}$, so lets assume your fish is spherical with a circular front of diameter $d$ ( ugly "*ugly*" fish).
Now instead of seeing a fish flowing in a straight line with velocity $v$ lets see from the fish's perspective, it seems that water is flowing towards us with velocity $v$. This seems to be like a normal flow of water through a pipe of cross sectional diameter $d$, Assuming that the fish is not disturbing the water on its side but only that on its front (too idealistic !)

Then reynolds no can be calculate as

> $R_e = {(\rho v d)}/{\eta}$
>       For turbulence, $R_e > 4000$; Calculate for v.
>       $\rho$ is density of liquid, $\eta$ is viscosity of liquid

Comment: No for turbulence flow Re > 4000.

Comment: Yes, it is thanks for pointing out, I wrote the transitional one from memory which also happens to be 2300 :P

Comment: A fish is probably more like a NACA airfoil, let's just say NACA 0012 for the sake of argument, in which case the turbulent transition is really $R_e \approx 3e6$. None of your analysis is wrong of course, but I would choose a much better shape than a spherical fish.

Comment: @tpg2114 what shape would you suggest?

Comment: Boss, what is the answer? How did you get it? What does this Reynold's number tell you? How do I calculate V when there aren't any V constants in the formula?

Comment: @tpg2114 : ever heard of [spherical cows](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) ?

Comment: @ Arjun Nagarajan : just apply the values for density, viscosity and your supposed diameter of face of fish and calculate maximum velocity it can move with by comparing it with 4000.

Comment: @rijulgupta Sure, but why make a bad simplification when an equally simple one is a better approximation and introduces zero additional complexity?

Comment: Gags maybe ! Anyway I liked your answer and gave it +1.